# getting duplicated text while using react simple chatbot api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chatbot

I am getting duplicates text when using options

this is the steps I have used:

```
const steps = [
    {
        id: '1',
        message: 'Those Are The Services That I am offering ,Please Choose A Service?',
        trigger: '2',
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        options: [{
                value: "Web Developement",
                label: 'Web Developement',
                trigger: '3'
            },
            {
                value: "Data Science",
                label: 'Data Science',
                trigger: '4'
            },
            {
                value: "AI & Deep Learning",
                label: 'AI & Deep Learning',
                trigger: '4'
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: '3',
        message: 'Wrong answer, try again.',

    },
    {
        id: '4',
        message: 'Awesome! You are a telepath!',

    },
];
```

and this the result I have got:
[the dupliacted text is indicated in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bArWH.png)

I have tried to create an otion for the users so they can pick an answer I was expecting to get just 3 otions while I got 6 with 3 duplicates.

Comment: Browsing the documentation's examples I see steps is an object containing an array, not an array. That would make it const steps = {[ ... ]}; rather than const steps = [ ... ]; Let me know if that does something, if not please provide a bigger code example

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and solved it by modifying `index.js`:

Before:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

After:

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import App from './App';

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Or removing StrictMode:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);
```